# What are BLPOP, BRPOP, and BRPOPLPUSH in Redis?

Tags: redis, monitoring

Was trying to study the metrics of Redis and came along these terms. Have no idea about them. Can someone please explain the terms in lay man words?

Comment: They are all described here... https://redis.io/commands

Answer (score 5):

As Per [REDIS Commands Documentation](https://redis.io/commands) :

> **BLPOP**
>
> [BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) is a blocking list pop primitive. It is the blocking
>   version of LPOP because it blocks the connection when there are no
>   elements to pop from any of the given lists. An element is popped from
>   the head of the first list that is non-empty, with the given keys
>   being checked in the order that they are given.
>
> In Brief : See [BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/blpop)
>
> **BRPOP**
>
> [BRPOP](https://redis.io/commands/brpop) is a blocking list pop primitive. It is the blocking
>   version of RPOP because it blocks the connection when there are no
>   elements to pop from any of the given lists. An element is popped from
>   the tail of the first list that is non-empty, with the given keys
>   being checked in the order that they are given.
>
> In Brief : See [BRPOP](https://redis.io/commands/brpop)
>
> **BRPOPLPUSH**
>
> [BRPOPLPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/brpoplpush) is the blocking variant of RPOPLPUSH. When source
>   contains elements, this command behaves exactly like RPOPLPUSH. When
>   used inside a MULTI/EXEC block, this command behaves exactly like
>   RPOPLPUSH. When source is empty, Redis will block the connection until
>   another client pushes to it or until timeout is reached. A timeout of
>   zero can be used to block indefinitely.
>
> In Brief : See [BRPOPLPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/brpoplpush)